# iOS - Hide App icon From Springboard

Tags: ios, iphone, springboard

The requirement is to hide the app from  the springboard and access it from any other apps. And the hidden app should be shown in settings.

I tried this in Info.plist:

```
<key>SBAppTags</key>
<array>
<string>hidden</string>
</array>
```

It worked on the simulator, but not on a real device.
I am using iOS 11.

Answer (score 0):

Apple **does not allow** to hide an icon for apps on the App Store from the homescreen. The method you are using is not officially suported, hence the mixed results.

Comment: I am looking for this requirement in a B2B app. So, it doesn't matter if app store won't allow for this.

Comment: did u find anything regarding this @poojabhasin